# Python dictionary comprehension using locals() gives KeyError

Tags: python, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

```
>>> a = 1
>>> print { key: locals()[key] for key in ["a"] }
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <dictcomp>
KeyError: 'a'
```

How can I create a dictionary with a comprehension like this?

It should result in `{"a": 1}`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A dict comprehension has its *own namespace*, and `locals()` in that namespace has no `a`. Technically speaking, everything but the initial iterable for the outermost iterable (here `["a"]`) is run almost as a nested function with the outermost iterable passed in as an argument.

Your code works if you used `globals()` instead, or created a reference to the `locals()` dictionary *outside* of the dict comprehension:

```
l = locals()
print { key: l[key] for key in ["a"] }
```

Demo:

```
>>> a = 1
>>> l = locals()
>>> { key: l[key] for key in ["a"] }
{'a': 1}
>>> { key: globals()[key] for key in ["a"] }
{'a': 1}
```

Comment: why in the world to dict comprehensions have their own namespace?

Comment: @dbliss: because generator expressions do. And list comprehensions after Python 2.7. And set comprehensions. It makes the implementation cleaner and keeps the names local (so they don't leak to the surrounding scope).

Answer (score 2):

You can try using `globals()` instead:

```
print {key : globals()[key] for key in ["a"]}
```

since `a` is not defined in the scope of the dict comprehension (as @MartijnPieters said).

Comment: And what if this is inside of a function?

Comment: Then creating a reference to `locals()` before the dict comprehension will work.